# wrong output in file problem but when i replace 7 with 1 correct output comes

Tags: c, file

[image: this is the text file]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{ FILE *fp;
char a=0;
fp=fopen("number.txt","r");
while(a!=EOF)
{
a=fgetc(fp);
if(a%7==0)
printf("%c",a);
} 
fclose(fp);
}
```

here I am trying to read number from a txt file stored in pc(where the c file of this prog is saved), I was trying to check whether the numbers in file are divisible by 7 if yes then printing them but its not giving the correct output. when  I replace 7 with 1 the correct output comes.

Comment: If you are testing every *digit* (byte) then `'7'` is ASCII `55` which is not divisible by `7`. However `'1'` is ASCII `49` and so this does work. If you test `(a - '0') % 7` this will work.

Comment: What do you expect `fgetc` to do? Maybe read: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html

Comment: OT: `char a=0;` --> `int a=0;`

Comment: Following the edit posting the file, `fgetc` does not read an integer but a single character.

Comment: The check for EOF shall be **after** `fgetc` and **before** using `a`. But then again... you shouldn't use `fgetc` at all

Comment: if fgetc cant do the job so which function shall I use to read the integer and check if multiple of 7 and then print it.

Comment: Here's what your code is doing:  It's reading the characters one at a time, and treating the character codes as integers.  So first it reads `'7'`, then another `'7'`, then a space `' '`, etc.  Instead, you need to read a sequence of integers, converting them to an integer, and skipping spaces.

Comment: Have a look at `fscanf().` For example `int a; while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &a) == 1)`

Comment: fscanf did the job, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`fgetc` reads characters one-by-one. So your code will read the characters:

`'7','7',' ','7','8',...`. which as numbers are: `55,55,32,55,56,...` Not what you want...

What you want are numbers like `77,78,...`.

One way to read a number from a file is `fscanf`. Something like:

```
int a;
while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &a) == 1)
{
    if(a % 7 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d", a);
    } 
}
```